# Docusign E-Signature default position and colour change

Tags: docusignapi

Can the Docusign default signature position in the document and font colors be changed in an embedded signing ceremony using API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the position is not defaulted, you have to choose where to plan tabs for signature each time. You can specify it using the API in a couple of ways. Either using X/Y coordinates or using anchorString which is a text that DocuSign looks for in the document to position the signing element.
I need to check for the color but as far as I can tell you can select font colors on elements like text, but not a signature color which I believe is limited to black at this point.